# Jquery $ajax funtion returns 500 Internal Server Error in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

when clicking a button I am passing some data to .cs file after page load.But I got **500 Internal Server Error** while calling ajax function.

Ajax Function,

```
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/getSelectedData",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                //async: true,
```

calling Function,

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public List<pageResult> getSelectedData(string search_value)
{}
```

I got the following error,

```
 **POST http://localhost:4519/Home.aspx/getSelectedData 500 (Internal Server Error)**
```

Comment: Error in the server code/code behind - turn human readable error codes on in the server environment.

Comment: maybe is something wrong with this: 
type: "POST"
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

Comment: alrready I tried without this but those are not working

Comment: What kind of data are you passing?

Comment: Iam passing string value

Comment: try using the [HttpPost] decorator on your controller

Comment: you're POSTing to a GET method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the .cs file like this,

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<pageResult> getSelectedData(string search_value)
{}
```

For ajax calling in aspx you should define the method as **Static** then only it will working for you.

Answer (score 2):

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so `application/json`;

The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

If you use `application/json`, you have to use **JSON.stringify()** in order to send JSON object.

**JSON.stringify()** turns a javascript object to json text and stores it in a string.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Home.aspx/getSelectedData",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 0):

change your ajax type to **get**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "Home.aspx/getSelectedData",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Now I got the error like this   jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:4519/Home.aspx/getSelectedData?search_value=%2FGossip 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: try url like this `"Home/getSelectedData"` @chozharajan